# Is there a way to get Z value from 3D multipoint shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, 3d, altitude, multipoint

Is there a way to get Z value/height/altitude from 3D multipoint shapefile in QGIS? All I found is way through SpatiaLite or PostGIS as explained here:

http://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/transfer-3d-shapefiles-z-values-to-the-table-of-attributes/

But conversion multipoint to point using *Vector/Geometry tools/Multipart to singlepart* drops the Z value. I opened DB manager, select DB and run SQL command in SQL window:

```
update tablename set columnname = st_z(st_pointn(geom,1)
```

In my case:

```
update lidar_pts set z= st_z(st_pointn(GEOMETRY,1))
```

First there was missing "**)**" at the end, second: *no such column: geom*. So I changed it to "GEOMETRY" which end up running but all z values become Null.

Is there a better/other way in QGIS 2? Or at least is there a way to convert multipoint to point directly in SpatiaLite so it will keep z geometry?

Comment: Also I have above 3M points in this file and have a lot of files... GDAL?

Comment: For the multipoint to point part, try ogr2ogr with parameters -nlt POINT25D -explodecollections http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html.

Comment: @user30184 thank you, I can see there also -zfield field_name which could work for me, going to try that

Comment: The -zfield works the other way around - fill z geometry from column. So thanks to "-nlt POINT25D -explodecollections -lco SHPT=POINTZ" I am able to convert 3D multipoint to 3D point. But running that SQL returns null to z column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding the current version of QGIS does not have 3D capabilities. You would have do, as you stated, 3D work in PostGIS or Spatialite. There may be a method to do the 3D functions you are inquiring about in Grass, which has a QGIS plugin.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to learn a bit more about GRASS and now I use GRASS GIS for all 3D processing - getting Z values from 3D / 2.5 D objects and saving to ascii x,y,z etc.

Comment: Glad you found a way, and it is working for you

Answer (score 3):

The upcoming QGIS 2.14 will have the necessary 3D-capabilities. I have tried it with 2.13 (Dev-version) and it works well: [Article using z-values with QGIS 2.14](http://isticktoit.net/?p=1359)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change the second part of the SQL-Statement:
e.g. update lidar_pts set z= st_z(GEOMETRY)
It worked fine for me with mulitpart-points - documented here http://isticktoit.net/?p=1117

Comment: Thank you, will try later. Meanwhile I decided to use GRASS to get Z value from 3D data. That is pretty helpful especially because I need  here and there also import DXF files with 3D objects / meshes / lines / points.

Comment: In 2.13 (2.14) you also have to use GRASS for generating the 3D-FeatureClass (SHP) - but now you can work with the z-values within the table/field-calculator of QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Try : [How to create a 3D shapefile from a raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57091/how-to-create-a-3d-shapefile-from-a-raster)

Use libraries as shapely or fiona (included in QGis python), extracted z value, you can add for example to attribute table.

Comment: Could you please explain how a solution with *raster* input would apply to a question about a *shapefile* input?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57138/28647 - In this answer is your problem.