# Extract height values from vector to CSV

Tags: qgis, csv, elevation, altitude

I have generated a CSV file (using the MMQGIS plugin) expecting to obtain all the coordinates of a vector layer that I have created. But the output file only contains the latitude and longitude coordinates (and a third column for the shapeid's). Is there a way to obtain also the altitude values?

Edit:

The first picture is from a KML that allows me to add the altitude column in the attributes list, and the second one is from a KML that just adds a column of zeros:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normally Z-coords are not included in a shapefile as a geometry. Can you describe what features (attributes) your table include? What is the data source of the shapefile you use?

Comment: Hi, the MMQGS plugins generates two output files: temp-attributes.csv and temp-nodes.csv. The first file doesn't contain any information (is just a table of one row) and the second one has three columns: [shapeid , latitude , longitude]. The source I used to create a vector layer by hand was Open Street Map... is this what you were asking?

Comment: Looks like this one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108833/is-there-a-way-to-get-z-value-from-3d-multipoint-shapefile-in-qgis

Comment: @mpm247 I am not sure that OSM has  a Z-coordiante. It might be that any altitude / height attribute if any would be documented in a double precision / float field. Any how, note that mmQGIS has two export to csv tools. If you wish to get attributes you should use the [attributes export...](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) tool

Comment: Okay, I will try to get the altitudes as attributes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From QGIS 2.14 and on:

Create attribute and fill with field calculator with expression:

> z ($geometry)

---

Screenshot from my data.

Version QGIS: 2.16.0 EPSG:28992

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for something like this. I will try if it works for me.

Comment: One last question, do you know why sometimes the command z($geometry) just provides a new attribute column full of zeros? I have tried it with KML's that I have stored in my computer and it worked, but if I right-click a vector layer created by hand in QGIS and I do a "Save As KML", when I open the field calculator of the new KML file the command that you suggested doesn't work (all zeros). Do you know why?

Comment: As far as I know QGIS doesn't support inserting / updating z-values. I think the points you created in QGIS are 2D and have z-values that are zero. (Adding a point in PostGIS to a 3DPoints table with QGIS 2.16.0 gave me this result.) This is easy to check with the Identify Features as the first printscreen shows.

Comment: Oh I see... I though that QGIS always works in three-dimensions, or that at least it was able to provide the altitude of a given pair of latitude-longitude coordinates. I am not able to post images here, so I will put two captures of my "identify features" window in a comment below (or above?) so that you can check if you see something wrong.

Comment: @mpm247 could you please set this answer as the correct one? That wil mark this question answered and removes it from the to do lists.