# Convert 3d shapefile to 2d in QGIS

Tags: qgis

How can I convert a 3d polyline shape to a 2d in QGis?

Comment: Did you try
right click -> save as 
and then **not** to check the box "include z values" ?

Comment: Very good!
how can i make this processe automatic?
I mean if i have 100 shapes is there a command to repeat the action for all files instead doing this one by one?

Comment: To have your question answered, please post it as a new question, rather than as an answer to an old question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/154762)

Answer (score 4):

Save a copy with Save vector layer as...
Take care that the Include z-dimension option is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Hi, but if you do that way you lose the z value, how can you keep the z value in the attributes table?

Comment: If you convert shapefile from XYZ into XY then of coarse you will lose the Z. But you can save it as an attribute by using the field calculator and function called "z". Field calculator is documented http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html.

Comment: Hi, if a 3D shapefile is used, ie in its internal geometry is 3D when converting to 2D the Z value is lost, have you tried it?

Attached example of curves in 3D geometry, thanks!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8x0acw9mjo1exh/LINEAS3D_EJEMPLO.zip?dl=0

Comment: 3D means XYZ coordinates, 2D means XY. If you convert from 3D into 2D the only thing that happens is that Z-coordinates are removed. It is impossible to avoid that. But you can create a new attribute for Z into the attribute table and populate it with the Z values with field calculator before you drop Z from the geometries..

Comment: You can learn how to use the field calculator from the answer to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202805/extract-height-values-from-vector-to-csv.